# How to expand a grid around a specific point in an matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, grid, robotics, robot

I have the following array and I would like to expand an area around X and turn array elements around X from 0 to 1. Any suggestions on how to do it?

From this array

```py
[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,x,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

To this array

```py
[[0,0,1,1,1,0,0],
 [0,0,1,x,1,0,0],
 [0,0,1,1,1,0,0]]
```

Comment: What have you tried ? SO is not a coding service ;)

Comment: Is this a numpy array, or a plain python list? I’ll second what @azro said.

Comment: Oh and how much information about `x` do you have? Is the array guaranteed to contain only zeroes and `x`?

Answer (score 0):

Not the optimal solution, but works for me. I use ROS and nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid message:

```
    def draw_thickened_grid_point(self, index):
        indexes_arround = []
        indexes_arround.append(index + 1)
        indexes_arround.append(index - 1)
        indexes_arround.append(index + self._map_width)
        indexes_arround.append(index - self._map_width)
        indexes_arround.append(index + self._map_width+1)
        indexes_arround.append(index + self._map_width-1)
        indexes_arround.append(index - self._map_width+1)
        indexes_arround.append(index - self._map_width-1)
        self._grid.data[int(index)] = 100
        for ind in indexes_arround:
            if(self._grid.data[int(ind)] == 0):
                self._grid.data[int(ind)] = 30
```

Answer (score -1):

Here a possible solution, it could be improved. I am really interested to see a better implemenentation.

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
            if (a[i][j] =="x"):

                if(len(a)>i+1):
                    a[i+1][j] =1
                    if(len(a[i])>j+1):
                        a[i+1][j+1] =1
                    if(len(a[i])>j-1):
                        a[i+1][j-1] =1

                if(len(a)>i-1):
                    a[i-1][j] =1
                    if(len(a[i])>j+1):
                        a[i-1][j+1] =1  
                    if(len(a[i])>j-1):
                        a[i-1][j-1] =1
                if(len(a[i])>j+1):
                        a[i][j+1] =1
                if(len(a[i])>j-1):
                        a[i][j-1] =1
```

print(a)

Comment: This is almost certainly not the best solution.

Comment: As I said, it could be improved. Still better than yours ;)

Comment: I haven’t written a solution because OP’s post is woefully lacking in detail and I do not wish to encourage extremely low quality questions. Also, is the array element actually the string `’x’`, or is `x` just a variable?